# (e)grep and atomic grouping [comprehension question]

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

I am trying to understand the correct use of »*[atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)*« a.k.a. »*independent subexpressions*« a.k.a. »*non-backtracking subpattern*« [this are the terms I found for the same thing, which doesn't make it less complicate]

- `egrep '123(?>fruit|juiceomatic)machine'` means: look for
  `123fruitjuiceomaticmachine`
- BUT **stop trying to match** [the rest of]
  the round brackets' content if `123` is followed by anything else than `fruit`!

**Is this correct? Did I miss something important?**

I ask this because I got to the expected results most of the time but I am not 100% sure if this is because I did it right or I just made lucky guesses.

Comment: That is not supported by ERE (egrep). If your grep supports `-P` (PCRE), you can use that.

Comment: @jordanm I get quite the results I am looking for without using `-P`. I'm on a GNU/Linux [Debian based] OS. Could this be connected to GNU ERE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an extended regular expression (ERE). `egrep` will interpret this as `123` followed by either `>fruit` or `juiceomatic` (the `?` is ignored) followed by `machine`. This means it will match on:

```
123>fruitmachine
123>juiceomaticmachine
```

but not:

```
123fruitjuiceomaticmachine
```

The `(?>...)` notation is from PCRE and means *non-capturing atomic group*, see `pcresyntax(3)`. You can use those with GNU grep and the `-P` switch.

If I understand you correctly you require `123` to be followed by `fruit` which in turn may be followed by `juiceomatic` or nothing. In that case I think `123fruit(|juiceomatic)machine` is the ERE you want.

Comment: So this command is connected to PCRE; thus the `-P` option is needed, as @jordanm already explained. This might also explain why I found so much examples in Perl [the Language itself] but nearly non within `grep` :)

What I gave as an example wasn't what I was actually looking for, but an example I came up with myself after learning the difference between Basic [BRE) and Extended Regular Expressions [ERE] the hard way.